# Problema: tenho duas strings, se preencho todas as posições da primeira, ela concatena com o valor da segunda

Tags: c, string

Um simples algoritmo para comparar dois cpfs:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char cpf[11], cpfBusca[11];

    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        cpf[i] = '\0';
        cpfBusca[i] = '\0';
    }

    printf("Digite seu CPF: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(cpf);
    system("cls");
    printf("Digite o CPF para comparacao: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(cpfBusca);
    system("cls");

    if(strcmp(cpf, cpfBusca) == 0) printf("O CPF esta cadastrado.\n");
    else printf("O CPF nao esta cadastrado!\n");

    //só para conferir
    printf("%s\n", cpf);
    printf("%s\n", cpfBusca);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Com um compilador online (normalmente compilo com o gcc), vi que o valor acabava sendo concatenado e isso só acontece quando preencho todos os 11 caracteres da primeira string, por que isso está acontecendo? Em um outro algoritmo que fiz uns dias atrás dava certo, mas fui testá-lo novamente e aconteceu o mesmo problema, estou confuso.

Comment: Em C uma string é um array de caracteres acrescido do caractere terminador '\0'. Assim para armazenar um número de cpf de 11 posições você vai precisar declarar uma string de 12 posições. No seu caso provavelmente a primeira entrada escreveu o caractere terminador fora da área de memória reservada para ela (ocupando a primeira posição do segundo cpf), ao ler o segundo cpf o caractere terminador foi sobrescrito pelo primeiro caractere do segundo cpf e o caractere terminador também foi escrito fora da área reservada para ele mas que não foi sobrescrita por nenhuma outra variável.

Comment: Declare suas string com comprimento 12.

Comment: Que sacanagem, nunca me disseram isso. Obrigado!

Comment: @anonimo dessa forma funcionou, obrigado!